# BIOS doesn't detect USB Mouse, Keyboard on first boot (only detects them after reset)

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, bios

My Motherboard/BIOS doesn't detect USB devices (Mouse, Keyboard) when I cold boot my computer (booting after complete shutdown). BIOS is always showing me 0 Keyboard / 0 Mouse / 2 USB Hosts connected. If I press the reset button at that point, my computer reboots and BIOS will recognize all devices. Fastboot is OFF.

**This means that I have to press the reset button on my computer after every cold boot.** I can't figure out what's causing this

- If I don't press the reset button during first boot and let my PC continue to boot with 0 Mouse / 0 Keyboard detected, they will NOT be detected by the operating system either (Ubuntu, Windows 10, Hackintosh).
- BIOS recognizes that 2 USB Hosts are connected (front panel USB Ports on my Case)
- The LEDs of my Keyboard and Mouse stay off when they are not detected by BIOS (they don't get any power at all).
- The problem persists regardless of which Keyboard, Mouse or USB Port I use (Apple Keyboard, WASD Keyboard, Corsair K65 Keyboard, Logitech MX 518 & G502 Mouse)

**I'm using the following BIOS Settings potentially relevant to USB:**

- Fastboot: Disabled
- POST Report: 5 Sec
- Boot up NumLock State: Enabled
- Interrupt 19 Capture
- Legacy USB Support: AUTO
- Intel xHCI Mode: Smart Auto
- EHCI Hand-off: Disabled
- Launch CSM: Enabled
- Boot device control: UEFI and Legacy OPROM
- Boot from storage devices: Legacy OPROM first

**Hardware:**
Asus Maximus VII Hero (Z97, BIOS Version 3201 x64), Intel 4790K, 32GB RAM, GTX 1080

Comment: In most cases I have seen you had to mess about with the Intel xHCI Mode and the EHCI Hand-off. Some combinations just don't work. Be advised that changing these may affect how your OS detects the USB devices.

Comment: Thanks, I think I solved my problem following your comment (see my Answer below). I think this was caused by a combination of things, namely EHCI Hand-off, but also **Auto** settings not working as they should. Lesson learned: don't trust "**Auto** settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I've found a solution following Tonnys comment.  Hopefully this will help someone with the same issue. Read carefully so you don't have to reset your CMOS like I had to.

1. I had to set `EHCI Hand-off` to `Enabled`,
2. **This is important:** I also needed to change `Legacy USB Support` from `Auto` to `Enabled`.

I left `Legacy USB Support` set to `Auto` first, which caused my Motherboard to not detect USB Devices during boot AT ALL (not even after reset) and I was locked out of BIOS completely. I guess `Auto` doesn't work as it should. I had to clear my CMOS in order to be able to get back into BIOS.

Comment: Good job! If I remember correctly: EHCI Hand-off is a requirement for USB Legacy to work correctly. Some Bios will silently enable EHCI hand-off if USB legacy support is needed, while others need both settings to be explicitly set.